# If less than IE9

Tags: conditional-tags

I've setup two Sidebars, am running a php browser detection plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/php-browser-detection/ and am trying to use the code below to show the countdown-ie sidebar on Internet Explore less than version 9.  Unfortunately, IE 9 is still pulling in the countdown sidebar.

```
<?php if (is_lt_IE9()) : ?> 
    <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar ('countdown-ie')) : else : ?> 
        <div class="pre-widget"> <p><strong>Widgetized area 1</strong></p> 
        <p>This panel is active and ready for you to add some widgets via the WP Admin</p> 
        </div> 
    <?php endif; ?> 
<?php else : ?> 
    <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar ('countdown')) : else : ?                 > 
      <div class="pre-widget"> <p><strong>Widgetized area 2</strong></p> 
      <p>This panel is active and ready for you to add some widgets via the WP Admin</p> 
      </div> 
    <?php endif; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here's a link: http://steveabraham.com/

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What did php-browser-detection support say? Can you indent your code? There's a lot of PHP tag spam in there, it makes it difficult to read the code

Comment: Try some CSS-Hacks instead

Comment: Can I ask why you're browser sniffing? You've also got a syntax error with a closing tag `?         >`

Comment: `is_lt_IE9()` is deprecated, should not matter, but the new syntax is `if( is_ie() && get_browser_version() < 9 )`

Comment: I indented the code to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my ammended version of your code:

```
<?php
if( is_ie() && get_browser_version() < 9 ) {
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'countdown-ie' ) ) {
        dynamic_sidebar( 'countdown-ie' );
    } else {
        ?>
        <div class="pre-widget">
            <p><strong>Widgetized area 1</strong></p> 
            <p>This panel is active and ready for you to add some widgets via the WP Admin</p> 
        </div>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'countdown' ) ){
        dynamic_sidebar ('countdown');
    } else {
        ?>
        <div class="pre-widget">
            <p><strong>Widgetized area 2</strong></p>
            <p>This panel is active and ready for you to add some widgets via the WP Admin</p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Changelog:

- Your initial check now uses the `is_ie` and `get_browser_version` functions
- Fixed PHP tag spam. There's no need to wrap every statement in PHP tags, it's just extra effort to type out
- Switched to the original conditional syntax of `if () {} else {}` to simplify
- Indented HTML
- Removed trailing spaces
- Fixed a broken closing PHP tag `?      >`
- dynamic_sidebar always exists, you should be checking if there are any widgets in that sidebar instead, so use `is_active_sidebar`
- Some wordpress coding standards fixes

### A final note

You shouldn't be sniffing the user browser. This code will fail if you have caching enabled ( user 1 is on IE, page gets cached, user 2 is on firefox but sees cached IE page.. )

Comment: That worked, the countdown in the footer breaks in IE less than 9, so I setup a second version for those browsers.  I tested on IE-Tester and the two versions seem to be able to display simultaneously, so I don't think we have any issue with Caching.  Thanks for the help!